# Getting Real-time data from MySQL db to update tables on a website?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

So I have built a basic application so far, with C# and .NET. I am using MVC and I have linked MySQL database from my server to my application. Using ADO.NET database models I have automatically generated the static data that is saved in the db from my models to my views, the CRUD operations are in the controllers. I want to add a real-time update feature to this. My current db is not hooked up to live data but in the future my data will be changing all the time with about 5 tables with 10 rows each that I need to update constantly. I need to do a lot more than CRUD so I am wondering what option would be the best to have this data update by itself?

1. I can use Ajax and jQuery to make calls back to my db and listen for changes or update on a timer. (Not quite sure how to do this, but I get the concept of making Ajax calls and having Jquery listen and wait on a timer)
2. Maybe use Wcf, but I feel as if I would have to start all over to do this.
3. Maybe a JS timer to refresh the page every five minutes or so but I think that if they were doing anything in the application it woudl mess them up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options for updating data on your web page:

- **Polling**- As you say, you can use a Javascript timer to fetch the new data via ajax.
- **Push**- You can use a library like [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) to have your server push changes to your webpage.

Factors in making this choice would be how instant you need the changes to be shown, and how much time you are willing to spend working on this. The Javascript timer will be simplest, but SignalR allows for instant updates and is more efficient bandwidth use, only sending data when it's needed.

Once you have the new data in Javascript, you can use a framework like [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) to update the DOM.